# Factorization of sum of two square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The difference is $a^2 - b^2 = (a - b).(a + b)$

But what about when I have $a^{25} + 1$ ? According to wolfram alpha, the alternate form is:

1. $(a+1) (a^4 -a^3 + a^2 -a + 1)( a^{20} - a^{15} + a^{10} -a^5 +1)$

However, the square root of 25 is a rational number 5.

But If I had 50, where the square root of 50 is irrational ?

1. $(a^2 + 1) (a^8 -a^6 +a^4 -a^2 +1) (a^{40} -a^{30} +a^{20} -a^{10} +1 )$

In fact, I'm just wondering and trying to find out patterns, I'm very curious about that, since I haven't found anything related, only the alternate forms generated by wolfram. My question is how and what mathematical algorithm they used to find $k$ forms for $a^n + 1$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such factorizations are special cases of general formulas for factorizations of cylotomic polynomials, e.g. see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). These formulas follow by [Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula).

Such polynomial factorizations come in handy for integer factorization. For example, [Aurifeuille, Le Lasseur and Lucas](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.114.548) discovered so-called [**Aurifeuillian factorizations**](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2006-75-253/S0025-5718-05-01766-7/S0025-5718-05-01766-7.pdf) of cyclotomic polynomials $\rm\;\Phi_n(x) = C_n(x)^2 - n\ x\  D_n(x)^2\;$. These play a role in factoring numbers of the form $\rm\; b^n \pm 1\:$, cf. the [Cunningham Project](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/). Below are some simple examples of such factorizations:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
x^4 + 2^2 \quad=&  (x^2 + 2x + 2)\;(x^2 - 2x + 2) \\\\
\frac{x^6 + 3^2}{x^2 + 3} \quad=&  (x^2 + 3x + 3)\;(x^2 - 3x + 3) \\\\
\frac{x^{10} - 5^5}{x^2 - 5} \quad=&  (x^4 + 5x^3 + 15x^2 + 25x + 25)\;(x^4 - 5x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 25) \\\\
\frac{x^{12} + 6^6}{x^4 + 36} \quad=&  (x^4 + 6x^3 + 18x^2 + 36x + 36)\;(x^4 - 6x^3 + 18x^2 - 36x + 36) \\\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is odd then the polynomial $p(x)=x^n+1$ has a zero at $x=-1$, $p(-1)=(-1)^n+1=-1+1=0$.  By the factor theorem, $x+1$ is therefore a factor of $p(x)$.  Using polynomial long division (or synthetic division) you can show that $x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}-\cdots-x+1)$.

For example, consider $p(x)=x^5+1$.  By the above, since $5$ is odd, $p(x)=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$.  Next notice that

$\begin{align*}x^{25}+1&=(x^5)^5+1=p(x^5)\\
&=(x^5+1)((x^5)^4-(x^5)^3+(x^5)^2-x^5+1)\\
&=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)(x^{20}-x^{15}+x^{10}-x^5+1).\end{align*}$

Finally, notice that $x^{50}+1=(x^2)^{25}+1=p((x^2)^5)$, so you can just substitute $x^2$ for $x$ in the factorization of $x^{25}+1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) about algorithms for factoring polynomials. For the special case of polynomials of the form $a^n + 1$ the factors will be [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial): more precisely,

$$a^n + 1 = \prod_{d | 2n, d \nmid n} \Phi_d(a).$$

For $n = 25$ the corresponding values of $d$ are $d = 2, 10, 50$, and for $n = 50$ the corresponding values of $d$ are $d = 4, 20, 100$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi/n}$, hence $z^n=-1$ and $z^{2k}$ from $k=1$ to $k=n$ are the $n$th roots of $1$. Then $a^n+1=a^n-z^n$ is the product of $a-z^{2k+1}$ from $k=1$ to $k=n$. One recovers a factorization on the real numbers by multiplying the $k$ term with the $n-k-1$ term for every $k\ne(n-1)/2$, since $(a-z^{2k+1})(a-z^{2n-2k-1})=a^2-2\cos((2k+1)\pi/n)a+1$.